# Should we roll back the edit to this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25059/254) was recently edited.

The edit changed the meaning of the question: so, existing answers no longer make sense (they are no longer an answer to the question).

Is this a problem, should we roll back (undo) the edit to the question?

I know that some other SE sites don't permit this kind of late edit to a question (I'm thinking of, for example, [About answer-invalidating edits](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2375/34757) on CodeReview.SE).

If you do permit the edit, should we delete the answers?

It's because we shouldn't delete the answers that I think the edit to the question is a type of vandalism.

If the OP wants to ask that new question, they can ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP doesn't want more answers, posted a comment:

> i am done with it, perhaps just close, i see no good coming out of it

... which I suppose is fair enough. So I rolled-back the edit and closed the question.